# Opencv(3.10) android- How to draw an object's trajectory

Tags: android, opencv

I have a project in college where I have to draw the trajectory of an object based on the color of it. Is being built based on colorBlobDetection. This is part of the code I have so far:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();


    if (mIsColorSelected) {
        mDetector.process(mRgba);
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
        Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
        Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);

        List<Moments> mu = new ArrayList<Moments>(contours.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            mu.add(i, Imgproc.moments(contours.get(i), false));
            Moments p = mu.get(i);
            int xContour = (int) (p.get_m10() / p.get_m00());
            int yContour = (int) (p.get_m01() / p.get_m00());
            Point ponto = new Point(xContour, yContour);
            //Imgproc.line(mRgba, ponto, ponto, CONTOUR_COLOR, 5, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0);
        }
```

At the moment I'm picking up the center of each contour.

Through the positions of the contours I want to draw their trajectories when they move

Ps. This 'Imgproc.line' was just to test if the center of each contour is correct.

Please help.

Comment: So what's your question? Please be a specific as possible so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very straightforward in my question.

Through the positions of the contours I want to draw their trajectories when they move